# Can you explain the Atom editor security model. Should I be careful when installing plugins?

Tags: security, atom-editor

Even though I don't have top secret data on my laptop, I wanted to know how careful should I be when installing Atom plugins.

I know these consists from coffee scripts and npm modules (at least some) and these are quite powerful.

Powerful because Atom is a "hackable editor" according to Wikipedia, and 
Npm modules can create connections to other computers and ...

Do you know solutions to possible improve the security? 
Currently, I check the code for every plugin I install but this is not a solution.

Comment: As I understand the word hackable in this context means "customizable". The customization happens by means of plugins. You should be able to read the code of plugins and determine if they are safe for your purpose.

Comment: I fully agree with you.